# java Mail API using to send email from a java program but showing error of SMTP protocol

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-mail

```
public class SendEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          String to = "sugandhnikhil@yahoo.com";//change accordingly  
          String from = "sugandh.nikhil@gmail.com";//change accordingly  
          String host = "localhost";//or IP address  

         //Get the session object  
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);  
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);  

         //compose the message  
          try{  
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));  
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
             message.setSubject("Ping");  
             message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");  

             // Send message  
             Transport.send(message);  
             System.out.println("message sent successfully....");  

          }catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}
    }

}
```

**Error :** `Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;`

All classes are added appropriately.i am not able to configure smtp.I tried out many Smtp Servers to be installed bit none of them worked.

Comment: Are you sure you are entering correct information for your SMTP? Seems to me like that is not the case. Unless you have an smtp server running on localhost ...

Comment: I'm in agreement with @Kris, do you have a mail server running locally and is it listening on port 25?  You can check in netstat to see if its listening on 25

Comment: The [Gmail instructions in the JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail) might be useful.

Comment: i am not able to configure or install an SMTP server any help is welcome